# SQL for selecting values in a single column by 'AND' condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table data like bellow

| PersonId | Eat |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | Carrot |
| 111 | Apple |
| 111 | Orange |
| 222 | Carrot |
| 222 | Apple |
| 333 | Carrot |
| 444 | Orange |
| 555 | Apple |

I need an sql query which return the total number of PersonId's who eat both Carrot and Apple.
In the above example the result is, **Result : 2**. (PersonId's 111 and 222)

An ms-sql query like 'select count(distinct PersonId) from Person where Eat = 'Carrot' and Eat = 'Apple''

Comment: You should add info to your question about why it fails (This will be helpful if someone read this in the future).

Comment: To solve this change `and` to `or`.

Comment: @Luuk - `or` isn't going to return ids that have **both**.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes changing to `or` wil return ids that have **both**  (but also some extra)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT PersonID FROM Person WHERE Eat = 'Carrot'
INTERSECT
SELECT PersonID FROM Person WHERE Eat = 'Apple'
```

Comment: " which return the total number of PersonId's"

Answer (score 2):

You can actually get the *count* without using a subquery to determine the persons who eat both.  Assuming that the rows are unique:

```
select ( count(distinct case when eat = 'carrot' then personid end) +
         count(distinct case when eat = 'apple' then personid end) -
         count(distinct personid)
       ) as num_both
from t
where eat in ('carrot', 'apple')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation of a sort:

```
select
personid
from <yourtable>
group by 
personid
having
count (case when eat = 'carrot' then 1 else null end) >= 1
and count (case when eat = 'apple' then 1 else null end) >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

At this example, I use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to make easy the count and transform 'Apple' and 'Carrot' to one string comparison:

```
create table #EatTemp
(
    PersonId int, 
    Eat Varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #EatTemp VALUES
 (111, 'Carrot')
,(111, 'Apple')
,(111, 'Orange')
,(222, 'Carrot')
,(222, 'Apple')
,(333, 'Carrot')
,(444, 'Orange')
,(555, 'Apple')

SELECT Count(PersonId) WhoEatCarrotAndApple FROM
(
    SELECT PersonId,
           STRING_AGG(Eat, ';')
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Eat) Eat
    FROM #EatTemp
    WHERE Eat IN ('Apple', 'Carrot')
    GROUP BY PersonId
) EatAgg
WHERE Eat = 'Apple;Carrot'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXISTS statements to achieve your goal.  Below is a full set of code you can use to test the results.  In this case, this returns a count of 2 since PersonId 111 and 222 match the criteria you specified in your post.

```
CREATE TABLE Person
  ( PersonId INT
  , Eat VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO Person
VALUES
(111, 'Carrot'), (111, 'Apple'), (111, 'Orange'),
(222, 'Carrot'), (222, 'Apple'), (333, 'Carrot'),
(444, 'Orange'), (555, 'Apple');

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PersonId)
FROM Person AS p
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
   FROM Person e1
   WHERE e1.Eat = 'Apple'
   AND p.PersonId = e1.PersonId)
AND EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
   FROM Person e1
   WHERE e1.Eat = 'Carrot'
   AND p.PersonId = e1.PersonId);
```

EXISTS statements have a few advantages:

- No chance of changing the granularity of your data since you aren't joining in your FROM clause.
- Easy to add additional conditions as needed.  Just add more EXISTS statements in your WHERE clause.
- The condition is cleanly encapsulated in the EXISTS, so code intent is clear.
- If you ever need complex conditions like existence of a value in another table based on specific filter conditions, then you can easily add this without introducing table joins in your main query.
- Some alternative solutions such as PersonId IN (SUBQUERY) can introduce unexpected behavior in certain conditions, particularly when the subquery returns a NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   count(PersonID) 
from Person 
where eat = 'Carrot' 
  and PersonID in (select PersonID 
                   from Person 
                   where eat = 'Apple');
```

Only selecting those persons who eat apples, and from that result select all those that eat carrots too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT (A.personID) FROM
(SELECT distinct PersonID FROM Person WHERE Eat = 'Carrot'
INTERSECT
SELECT distinct PersonID FROM Person WHERE Eat = 'Apple') as A
```